# Is Japanese whisky kosher?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, liquor-beer

[Here](http://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/food/its-suntory-time/2012/01/11/gIQAjuVy5P_story.html)'s an interesting article about whisky produced in Japan. Have any of the Kashrut authorities said anything about whether such whisky requires supervision? Do any such whiskies have supervision?

Neither [Kashrut.com](http://www.kashrut.com/articles/liquor2/) nor the [Star-K](http://www.star-k.com/cons-appr-liquor.htm) have addressed such liquor in particular on their lists. I wouldn't automatically assume that any rule applying to Scotch whisky would apply to Japanese whisky, since the production practices and legal regulations may be different.

Comment: All I can tell you is that Yamazaki 12 is awesome.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about all japanese whiskeys. However at [OnlyKosherWine.com](http://www.onlykosherwine.com/ProductList/Spirits/Japanese_Whiskey.html) they do have 2 whiskeys from Japan.

Comment: Does that store certify their stock as kosher according to any particular standards or authorities?

Comment: I do not know..

Comment: http://www.onlykosherwine.com/Contact-Us.html

Comment: ONLYKOSHERWINE.COM CARRIES SOME JAPANESE WHISKEY. AS WITH ALL WHISKEY ON OUR SITE UNLESS IT STATES CERTIFIED KOSHER WE MAKE NO REPRESENTATION AS TO THE KASHRUT OF WHISKEIES. THERE IS MUCH CONFUSION AS TO KASHRUT OF WHISKIES AND ITS FOR EVERYONE TO CONTACT THEIR LOCAL RABBI AS TO SPECIFIC PRODUCTS. OUR POLICY IS TO CARRY UNFLAVORED WHISKIES WITHOUR CERTIFICATION UNLESS WE HEAR OF A SERIOUS KASHRUS ISSUE WITH A SPECIFIC WHISKEY PRODUCT. ANY WINE OR FLAVORED ALCOHOL PRODUCT WILL NOT BE CARRIED ON OUR SITE UNLESS IT IS CERTIFIED KOSHER. I HOPE THIS ANSWERS THE QUESTION POSTED.

Comment: @MOSHEFINK, thanks very much for clarifying. (This was in response to a query I put on the contact form Gershon Gold suggested.)